# excel2latex leads to the error: "Unicode char 8... not set up for use with LaTeX"

Tags: unicode, excel, excel2latex

Compiling LaTeX to pdf worked fine until I used code generated by `excel2latex`. Now I'm getting the error "Unicode char 8… not set up for use with LaTeX".

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
\toprule
      & \textbf{Volume} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Phusion Taq Polymerase} & 0.5 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{5 ˣ Phusion buffer HF} & 10 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{dNTPs } & 1 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primer forward} & 2.5 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primer reverse} & 2.5 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{DNA} & 2 l \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Water} & 31.5 l \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that the problem is related to `5 ˣ `. Try to delete that symbol and type again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Hint: When an answer to a question of yours was helpful, you can
[accept the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (one answer per question) and once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [upvote answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your code I can see that there is a symbol with different font, that is, it looks like coming from a copy/paste procedure.

So, delete that character and type it as you wish.

Note the difference between your code `5 ˣ Phusion buffer HF` and my code `5 x Phusion buffer HF`.

I guess that what you want is `$5\times$ Phusion buffer HF`.